# how to click iframe using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I want to click an iframe's radio button, but it doesn't work.
my code is this.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
Url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIStvhR347g'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://video-download.online')
driver.find_element_by_id("link").send_keys(Url)
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
time.sleep(5)

#this part is problems... don't working
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("136-wrapper").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Proceed").click()
```

html source is this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script>
        if (top.location !== location) {
            top.location = self.location;
        }
        if (location.host !== 'video-download.online' && location.host !== 'beta.video-download.online') {
            eval("location.href=''+'//'+'video-download.online';");
        }
    </script>
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="author" content="Luca Steeb"/>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#008679"/>
<meta name="description" content="Download from this uploaded.net premium link generator with highspeed. For free."/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Video-Download.online"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Download videos, mp3s and playlists from 1979 sites - for free."/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="video-download.online"/>
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="1143492155680932"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="//video-download.online/img/logo.jpg"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?1"/>
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/img/logo_small.jpg"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Video-Download.online" href="/opensearch.xml"/>
<title>
Online Video Download
</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bt.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
<noscript><iframe height=0 src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TWMNRP"style=display:none;visibility:hidden width=0></iframe></noscript><script>!function(e,t,a,n,r){e[n]=e[n]||[],e[n].push({"gtm.start":(new Date).getTime(),event:"gtm.js"});var g=t.getElementsByTagName(a)[0],m=t.createElement(a),s="dataLayer"!=n?"&l="+n:"";m.async=!0,m.src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id="+r+s,g.parentNode.insertBefore(m,g)}(window,document,"script","dataLayer","GTM-TWMNRP")</script>

    <script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create','UA-54289597-5','auto');ga('send','pageview');</script>   

    <script>function send(action) { ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'download-' + action) }</script>
    <script async src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>function _(n,i){i?window[n]?i():setTimeout(function(){_(n,i)},100):window.jQuery?window.jQuery(document).ready(function(){n(window.jQuery)}):setTimeout(function(){_(n)},100)}</script>
</head>

<body>

    <header class="navbar navbar-info navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle no-waves" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="nav-brand">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        <img class="logo" src="/img/logo.svg" alt=""/>

                        <div class="parent">

                                Video-Download<small>.online</small>
                                <br/>
                                <span class="small-text">1979 sites officially supported</span>

                            <span id="changelog"></span>
                        </div>

                        <span class="clear"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <div class="social">
                    <div class="fb-like fb-nav" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/VideoDownload.online"
                         data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="social-close" title="Hide all social buttons">&times;</div>

                <li class=" ">
<a href="/">
    Home
</a>
</li>
                <li class=" ">
<a href="/sites">
    Sites
</a>
</li>
                <li class=" ">
<a href="/contact">
    Contact
</a>
</li>
                <!--html.navItem('/app', 'Mobile App')-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<noscript class="fixed">
    <div class="container">Please enable javascript. Video Download and almost all other sites don't work properly
        without it.
    </div>
</noscript>

<div id="alert" class="alert alert-fixed alert-dismissible m-t-15 hidden">
    <div class="container relative">
        <span id="alertText"></span>
        <span class="close-alert" onclick="_(function() { $('#alert').remove();$('body').removeClass('alert-showing') })" title="close">×</span>
    </div>
</div>

<main class="container">
    <div>
    <h1>Legal</h1>

    <div style="width: 50%;" class="center">

    </div>
</main>

<script src="/sweetalert/sweetalert.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sweetalert/sweetalert.css">  

<script src="/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */(function(d,s,a,i,j,r,l,m,t){try{l=d.getElementsByTagName('a');t=d.createElement('textarea');for(i=0;l.length-i;i++){try{a=l[i].href;s=a.indexOf('/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection');m=a.length;if(a&&s>-1&&m>28){j=28+s;s='';if(j<m){r='0x'+a.substr(j,2)|0;for(j+=2;j<m&&a.charAt(j)!='X';j+=2)s+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(j,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);j++;s=decodeURIComponent(s)+a.substr(j,m-j)}t.innerHTML=s.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');l[i].href='mailto:'+t.value}}catch(e){}}}catch(e){}})(document);/* ]]> */</script></body>
</html>
```

frame source is this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bt.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<style>body{margin:0!important;}tr{clear:both;cursor:pointer;}td{padding:0 20px 0 0;white-space:nowrap;}.radio{margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;}.small{padding:0;font-size:85%;}@media (max-width: 319px) {table{font-size:12px;}}@media (max-width: 480px) {td{padding:0 5px 0 0;}.small{font-size:50%;}}</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="format" method="post">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="isxklqy5blw9of7"/>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="undefined-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="undefined">
<input id="undefined" name="format" type="radio" value="undefined" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>I don't care</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="160-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="160">
<input id="160" name="format" type="radio" value="160" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>256x144</td>
<td></td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>23.2 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="133-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="133">
<input id="133" name="format" type="radio" value="133" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>426x240</td>
<td></td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>51.2 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="134-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="134">
<input id="134" name="format" type="radio" value="134" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>640x360</td>
<td></td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>65.4 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="135-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="135">
<input id="135" name="format" type="radio" value="135" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>854x480</td>
<td></td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>138.0 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="136-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="136">
<input id="136" name="format" type="radio" value="136" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>1280x720</td>
<td>HD</td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>272.2 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="298-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="298">
<input id="298" name="format" type="radio" value="298" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>1280x720</td>
<td>HD</td>
<td>
60 FPS
</td>
<td>385.0 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="137-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="137">
<input id="137" name="format" type="radio" value="137" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>1920x1080</td>
<td>Full HD</td>
<td>
30 FPS
</td>
<td>535.0 MB</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="small">
<div class="">
<div class="radio " id="299-wrapper">
<label class="text-capitalize" for="299">
<input id="299" name="format" type="radio" value="299" onchange="" undefined required />
<span class=circle></span><span class=check></span>
<span class="grey-text"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>1920x1080</td>
<td>Full HD</td>
<td>
60 FPS
</td>
<td>707.0 MB</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="btn center" type="submit">Proceed &raquo;</button>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    $('tr').click(function() {
        $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>
<script src="/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Waves.attach('.btn', ['waves-light']);
    Waves.init();
</script>
```

I tried these codes, but don't work.

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@name, "frame")]'))
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe'))
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
```

these iframe switching codes are any exception is nothing, but result is '[]'.

```
>>> driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe'))
>>> driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio']")
[]
>>> driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='radio']")[0].click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

thanks for your help

Comment: How is the code not working?  Are you getting error messages or is it just sitting there and doing nothing?

Comment: I getting error messages...

Comment: What error messages?

Comment: [link](http://i1.ruliweb.com/img/16/09/11/15714bacb20488758.png)

Comment: Could you share HTML source screenshot here with showing iframe as well

Comment: And provided link doesn't show anything need to check it..

Comment: but HTML source is so long... can you use firefox? this is hitml code. "view-source:https://video-download.online/"

Comment: I can click radio button in main html page, but I couldn't click radio button in iframe page...

Comment: Just shar problematic part of the HTML source screenshot, or share only iframe HTML here as you shared for other elements HTML. And I have also provided the answer to point out your mistakes according to your shared HTML, try with provided answer and let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming provided HTML is correct) actually your both locator is wrong to locate `radio button` element as well as `proceed button` element.

> driver.find_element_by_css_selector("136-wrapper").click()

Using [`css_selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) id locator used with `#`, so correct [`css_selector` with id](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp) should be `#136-wrapper`

But this locator will be locate to `<div>` element while you want `<input id="136" name="format" type="radio" value="136" onchange="" undefined required />` element, so here you can locate `radio button` and click using `find_element_by_id()` as :-

```
driver.find_element_by_id("136").click()
```

> driver.find_element_by_link_text("Proceed").click()

[`find_element_by_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text) works to locate only `<a>` anchor element with text while you want to locate `<button>` element, so this locator wouldn't work.

To locate `Proceed` button you should try using `find_element_by_xpath()` as  :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(text(),'Proceed')]").click()
```

Comment: your reply thanks, but don't work.   'driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))' <- I think this code don't switch iframe, maybe.

Comment: So that's why I'm saying could you please share iframe HTML, so I could provide you exact solution..

Comment: And also let me know is there any exception occurred during switching iframe and make sure desired element is inside an iframe

Comment: @User8392 Hey, in your whole HTML source, I can't see any `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tag, I'm just seeing `<form>` tag. Are you sure there is an `iframe` or just confused with `form` element??

Comment: Or if there is any iframe also share that HTML as well??

Comment: @User8392 Or try to switch with iframe id or name or src attribute value which identify correct iframe because if there are multiple iframes/frames present, this line `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe'))` will switch to first found iframe in order, and I think that's the reason in your case you can switch to iframe but nothing found inside it. Need to verify there is one iframe only or multiple frame/iframe present..